# Tribonacci generating matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

I know that $T(0) = 0$ and $T(1) = T(2) = 1$. For $n \ge 3$,

$$T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3)$$

Now I find that

$$\begin{bmatrix}T(n+1)\\T(n)\\T(n-1)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}T(n)\\T(n-1)\\T(n-2)\end{bmatrix} = \cdots=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^n\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I find now that
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix}
T(n+1)&T(n)+T(n-1)&T(n)\\T(n)&T(n-1) + T(n-2)&T(n-1)\\T(n-1)&T(n-2)+T(n-3)&T(n-2)\end{bmatrix}$$

Do I need to guess? Or there is a way to do it?

Comment: The power of the matrix should contain integers, not $T$'s.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't understand, I want to calculate $(n+1)th$ tribonacci number by powering matrix and I guess that's the answer.

Comment: Do you know how to [diagonalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization) a matrix?

Comment: Start with $n=2$ and you will see.

Comment: Do you have to diagonalize? You have a companion matrix.

Comment: I know how to diagonalize, will it help me?

Comment: Isn't it simply to do mathematical induction? Demand that $M^1 = [T(1),... ;...]$ then conclude from $M^n  \cdot M = M^{n+1}$ follows your result?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ah, I've never heard of a "companion matrix" before. I saw a matrix raised to $n$ and diagonalization is my go-to. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The thing is that I don't want to use induction. I know the answer because I found it but what if I wanted to obtain it myself? I managed to do find the matrix but I don't know how to recognize these values.

Comment: @Nerwena sure, diagonalization would help, since$$A^n=(P^{-1}DP)^n=P^{-1}D^nP$$where $A$ is the coefficient matrix you wrote above, and $D$ is diagonal so raising it to $n$ is trivial. But that may be overkill.

Comment: @user170231 Okay, but how does it help with my question? I don't really have a problem with power, I'm asking if there's a way to determine that the power of this matrix is equal to the matrix with tribonacci numbers or just to calculate it and prove by induction. In every paper I see it's just stated as 'note that'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is surely to get your transfermatrix, say $\mathbb M$, (that one with zeros and ones) as solution of one step of iteration.

So for instance $[T_0, T_1, T_2] \cdot \mathbb M = [T_1,T_2,T_3]  \Rightarrow \text{ find } \mathbb M$ . Now this simple ansatz does not yet help, because we cannot apply matrix-inversion on the one-row vector on the lhs.

But instead to have only a one-row vector on the lhs, we can construct square matrices $\mathbb T_0$,$\mathbb T_1$  to attempt $ \mathbb T_0 \cdot \mathbb M = \mathbb T_1  \Rightarrow \mathbb M = \mathbb T_0^{-1} \cdot \mathbb T_1$ :
$$ \begin{array}{ccc}  
   &  & \mathbb M  \\ 
   & * & ========\\
 \left[\begin{array}{}  T_0&T_1&T_2 \\T_1&T_2&T_3 \\T_2&T_3&T_4 \end{array}\right] 
   & = & 
\left[\begin{array}{}  T_1&T_2&T_3 \\T_2&T_3&T_4 \\T_3&T_4&T_5 \end{array}\right] \\
\end{array}
$$
Then $ \mathbb T_0 \cdot \mathbb M^n = \mathbb T_n$ by construction.

---

*Note: It would have been better to use small letters for scalar values and capital letters for the matrices, but well: I just used the "mathbb"-attribute for distinction*

Comment: Ah, @ParamanandSingh -thanks for the notification! I even wanted to expand/detail my complimentary comments, but was distracted. Good to be reminded :-)